# Is there a way to block any tabs from opening using browsers or code?

Tags: html, webhooks

I'm creating a program using IFTTT and Webhooks together to form a sign in application in HTML. I've linked buttons to a Webhooks call,

```
<input type="button" value="Room 100" id="myButton4" onClick="window.location.href = 'https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/room100/with/key/thujthrgdvfsd';">
```

but when clients click the buttons I want to block the Webhooks success message - "You have successfully fired the event" that opens in a new tab. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to open that link in same tab?

Comment: No, I want to block the tab from opening at all. Essentially when the button is clicked I just want the webhooks link to fire and that’s it.

Comment: Are you having any library in your code like jQuery or any other javascript framework?

Comment: Not yet, I was just looking through JavaScript libraries to see if any could aid me.